# New to Ruby - While loop issues in IRB

Tags: ruby

So a few days ago I decided I would try and learn Ruby and it's actually been going pretty well.  I've been mostly fiddling around in IRB until I can find a non-trivial program to code to test my knowledge.

However, today I ran into an unexpected issue with a While loop and I was hoping y'all could help me out with this:

```
irb(main):001:0> i = 0
=> 0
irb(main):002:0> while (i < 1000)
irb(main):003:1> i++
irb(main):004:1* end
SyntaxError: (irb):4: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
        from C:/WINDOWS/Ruby/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Why exactly isn't this working as I'm expecting it to?  According to [this site](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Control_Structures#while) I have the structure correct, so what am I missing here?

I'm running Ruby 1.9.2 under Windows XP, if that's of any help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`i++` is not valid ruby.  You need to do `i += 1`.

Edit:
See Mladen's comment as to what the parser is seeing.

Comment: It *is* valid Ruby, that's exactly *why* the error message is so confusing.

Comment: @Jörg: Not sure what do you mean: `end` is expected indeed, he has `+` instead. Or not?

Comment: @Mladen I guess technically it is valid (as far as I can tell) in ruby [+]+ == + so i+++++1 is the same as i + 1.  That's why it says unexpected end because it's expecting a number to add to i.  I think the correct answer to the question is that ++ is not a valid increment operator though :p

Comment: No, it's not valid Ruby. + in this context is a binary operator and there is no second operand. The error message isn't confusing given the above. Consider: `while true; i + end`

Comment: @Andrew: `i+++++1` seems to be parsed as `i+(+(+(+(+1))))`, `+` is valid unary operator, like `-`.

Comment: Thinking about it, `++i` _is_ valid Ruby. Although it doesn't do what Ruby immigrants are likely to expect. ;)

Comment: @Mladen Thanks for the info, I was sitting here trying to figure out what the parser was seeing in i++++1 that I wasn't :)

Comment: @Mladen Jablanović: it says that it expected something else instead of the `end`. Try putting something else (for example `0`) on the line after the `i++` and before the `end` and you will see that it gets parsed perfectly fine. It doesn't mean what the OP thinks it means, obviously. If, OTOH, `i++` *were* invalid Ruby, you would see a much more sane error message like, well, "++ is not a valid operator" or something like that. Instead, you get an error message that is indicating that the unary `+` operator is missing its operand.

Comment: @Joerg: So you decide whether a piece of code is valid not by whether it parses but what error it causes? BTW, you're right about the error message, it indeed suggests a missing operand.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby doesn't have C-style increment (`++`) or decrement (`--`) operators. You want this:

```
i = 0
while(i < 1000)
  i = i + 1 # Or i += 1
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless your purpose is specifically to understand how while loops and integer addition/comparison work, what you really want is

```
1000.times do |i|
end
```