# problem with if and else code... in ruby

Tags: ruby

Do not treat to the variables and conditions  ...

```
def index
end 

def search    
  count = 1
  while count < 3
    if count == 1
      @movie = "not found" if @code1 == nil || @code1 == ""
      if @movie == ""
      end
    end
    if count == 2
      @movie = "not found" if @code1 == nil || @code1 == ""
      if @movie == ""
        if @code1.include? "movshare"
        end
        if @code1.include? "novamove"
        end
      end 
    end
    count++
  end
end
end
```

what is the problem in this code? i get an error:
syntax error, unexpected keyword_end

Comment: `++` does not exist in ruby, that is one potential problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [New to Ruby - While loop issues in IRB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679808/new-to-ruby-while-loop-issues-in-irb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have one more unnecessary '`end`'. There are 9 opening clauses including `def, while and if` and 10 closing `end`

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the interpreter with your `count++`. `++` does not exist in Ruby. You need to use `count += 1`. The interpreter is probably assuming that is an expression involving addition, and expecting another operand but instead finding `end`